# XAML element inside of ItemsControl DataTemplate sometimes has null parent (WinRT)

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm making a win8 app. I have an ItemsControl with a DataTemplate. Inside this DataTemplate, there is a Grid. Inside this Grid there is a WebView and a ProgressRing. I have an event for LoadCompleted on the WebView, at which time I want to disable the ProgressRing. My thought was to use the following:

```
    ProgressRing pr = ((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent as Grid).Children.First(t => t.GetType().Equals(typeof(ProgressRing))) as ProgressRing;
    pr.IsActive = false;
```

And this works sometimes, but sometimes it claims that ((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent) is null. I verified from debugging that in these cases, the sender is still the correct WebView. The WebView is being shown on the screen and is formatted correctly - so how could its parent be null?

Here's the XAML:

```
               <ItemsControl Margin="40,0,40,0" x:Name="resultsItemsControl">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="50,0">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" MaxWidth="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" MaxWidth="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Grid.Column="0" x:Name="viewInBrowser" IsEnabled="False" Style="{StaticResource PreviewLinkAppBarButtonStyle}" Margin="0,0,40,0" Click="viewInBrowser_Click_1"></Button>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" Margin="0,20,0,20" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Georgia" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                <ProgressRing x:Name="loadingProgressRing" Margin="20,0" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="White" IsActive="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ProgressRing>

                                <WebView ScriptNotify="WebView_ScriptNotify_1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="14" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding CurrentSearchUrl}" Width="0" LoadCompleted="WebView_LoadCompleted_1"></WebView>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: you might want to wait before visual tree is constructed. Do your action after Loaded && LoadCompleted has been fired.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a WebView in an ItemsControl at all, but you could try putting your entire template in a UserControlm then you handle the event inside of the UserControl and don't need to care about sender, since you can just name the Grid and access a named Grid.